# How to add and remove active class to anchor tag within li using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need one help. I have multiple `li` values I need to add active class when clicked any value and removed from others using Jquery/Javascript.I am explaining my code below.

```
<ul id="ulCategory">
   <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABC</li> 
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABF</li>    
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABK</li>    

</ul>
```

My `active` class is given below.

```
.active {text-align: left; color: #fff; background-color:#ffbb00; text-decoration: none;}
```

Here I need while user will click on one value that only will be remain active and other will not have the active class.Please help me.

Comment: Please add a fiddle

Comment: to handle this use "toggleclass"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ulCategory li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
  })
})
function savesubcat(){
  return null
}
```

```css
.active {text-align: left; color: #fff; background-color:#ffbb00; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCategory">
   <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABC</li> 
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABF</li>    
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABK</li>    

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind a click handler to the elements in question and use the `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods.

Also, call your `savesubcat()` function from there too, rather than using the inline `onclick=` attribute.

```js
var anchors = $("#ulCategory li a").click(function() {
  //savesubcat()
  $(this).addClass("active")
  anchors.not(this).removeClass("active")
})
```

```css
.active {text-align: left; color: #fff; background-color:#ffbb00; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCategory">
   <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>ABC</li> 
   <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>ABF</li>    
   <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>ABK</li>    
</ul>
```

Put the JS at the end of the body, and/or wrap it in a document ready handler.

(I'm assuming the `savesubcat()` function doesn't cause page navigation or refresh, because if it did then any classes set *before* the refresh would be cleared.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul id="ulCategory">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="subcategory">ABC</li> 
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="subcategory">ABF</li>    
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="subcategory">ABK</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".subcategory").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active").not(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#ulCategory a").click(function() {

  $(this).addClass("active")
  $("a").not(this).removeClass("active")
})
```

```css
.active {
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ffbb00;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCategory">
  <li><a href='#'>ABC</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>ABF</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>ABK</a></li>

</ul>
```

1. Use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` with `not()`
2. In href use `#`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** and **[removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)** as below

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="ulCategory">
   <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABC</li> 
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABF</li>    
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABK</li>    

</ul>
```

**JQuery:**

```
 $("#ulCategory>li").click(function(){
   $("#ulCategory>li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/4918/)**

Answer (score 0):

use with `this` element in the function call

```js
function savesubcat(that){
$('#ulCategory li a').removeClass('active')
$(that).addClass('active')

}
```

```css
.active {
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ffbb00;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCategory">
  <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat(this)'>ABC</li> 
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat(this)'>ABF</li>    
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat(this)'>ABK</li>    

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add div to your "ul" tag and write onclick event on it.Try below code

```
//HTML   
 <div id="list_div">
      <ul id="ulCategory">
       <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABC</li> 
       <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABF</li>    
      <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABK</li>    
     </ul>
    </div>


//JS
     $(document).on("click","#list_div a",function() {   
           $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.abc').click(function () {
  $('.abc').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {text-align: left; color: #fff; background-color:#ffbb00; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <ul id="ulCategory">
        <li class="abc active"><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABC</li> 
        <li class="abc"><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABF</li>
        <li class="abc"><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='savesubcat()'>ABK</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings` method.

> `siblings` method gets the siblings of each element in the set of
>   matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').andSelf().siblings().removeClass();
});
```

```css
.active {text-align: left; color: #fff; background-color:#ffbb00; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCategory">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="subcategory">ABC</li> 
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="subcategory">ABF</li>    
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="subcategory">ABK</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
  $('ul li a').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass( "active" );
      $(this).addClass( "active" ); 
    });
```

```js
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass( "active" );
  $(this).addClass( "active" ); 
});
```

```css
.active {text-align: left; color: #fff; background-color:#ffbb00; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCategory">
   <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=''>ABC</li> 
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=''>ABF</li>    
<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=''>ABK</li>    

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ulCategory li a').click(function(){
    $('#ulCategory li a').removeClass("active")
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCategory">
<li><a>ABC</a></li> 
<li><a>ABF</a></li>    
<li><a>ABK</a></li>    
</ul>
```